# Swift - How to program a button to go to the mainScene, without segues going back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, viewcontroller

I am making a game that when you press the **start button** it takes you to the **game scene** and then with the game is **over** the **replay button will appear** on the screen, when that replay button is pressed it will take me to **main main screen** and **NOT** on my game scene. After a couple of hours browsing, I found something related to what I am looking for but it was in objective-c. The code in objective-C is down below please tell me what it means in swift, as I am not familiar with objective-c at all.

```
(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
{
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController;

    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your swift code:

```
@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController
}
```

Comment: nice one and useful answer too

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Dharmesh Kheni's Answer

You can also call the viewcontroller programmatically without segues.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeID") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can set the identifier for the viewcontroller you need to present, like this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: where would I write that line of code, under the back button where my 2nd viewcontroller takes me to my main menu?